# How to properly read from SerialPort C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, console.writeline

I have the following problem:

I read from serial port and i get very strange output.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization; 

namespace SerialPort_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static SerialPort mySerialPort;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 19200, Parity.Even, 7, StopBits.One);
            //mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM6", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);


            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.Open();
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_DataReceived);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        public static string clean(string s)
        {
            string ss = "";
            //s = string.Join("", Regex.Split(s, "(ID|I<|P<|V<|VI)").Skip(1));

            char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
            char[] db = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 
                            'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','X','Y','Z','<','|','0','1','2','3','4','5','6',
                            '7','8','9'};
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < db.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[i] == db[j])
                    {
                        ss += arr[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            return ss;
        }

        private static void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
        string s = clean(mySerialPort.ReadExisting().Replace("\r", "|"));

             Console.WriteLine(s);

        }

    }
}
```

My device is a ID/Passport reader connected to the USB port using a virtual comport I can get the data in but it is not consistent.

When I swipe my ID card the 1st time I get an output i.e.
(example)

> IDROU745357465<<<<<<<<|424762M46278738753753|ILI<

But the problem is that this should be 1 line only.

When I swipe it again I get a very different result and every time it comes different with every next slide

2nd time example:

> I DR OU
>
> 7 4535 7465<<<< << < < | 424 76 2M 46278 73 8 75375 3|I LI < < L A Z<
>   V K GHJDK <<<<<<<<<<<|

Kindly consider the spaces newlines since they appear as new lines!

And there is no pattern. I want to put all the buffered bytes in to one string. When I don't use

```
WriteLine();
```

It seems to be OK and I get it in a single line but I don't want it that way I need to use the

```
 WriteLine();
```

and to get a consistent output every time I swipe the card.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Regards,
Iliali

Comment: Don't replace newlines and debug your code with `Console.WriteLine("#" + +s +"#") ;` or `Console.Write` Seems like your device doesn't return all data in one "read".

Comment: When I use the `Console.WriteLine("#" + s +"#") ;` I just get instead of the new lines I get the substring surrounded with the # which is expected. However this shows me only that when I swipe the card the serial port buffer is not read fully but a part is read and then another part is read and then another part is read until the buffer is empty and all the new readings are placed in a new line because of the `WriteLine();` If I use the `Write();` I get the # in the beginning and one at the end. And that's all. Any ideas?

Comment: Now I noticed that if I use `Console.Write("#" + s +"#") ;` only the first input is as it should be i.e. `s` is a full string every next time I swipe the card I get the # surrounding almost every character.

Comment: Without having this device to debug, it is hard to answer authoritatively, but I am not sure your overall design will always work. [SerialPort.DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) From the documentation "The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received. Use the BytesToRead property to determine how much data is left to be read in the buffer."  Break your `clean(mySerialPort.ReadExisting().Replace("\r", "|"));` into each of its parts and debug each separately instead of as one line of code.

Comment: @IliaLazarov Can you try to read your data in a "thread" with `var stream = new StreamReader(mySerialPort.BaseStream);
            someloop{ stream.ReadLine(); }` without attaching to `DataReceived` event

Comment: I will try this later today when i have access to the device. Will let you know what happened